# Why is output of Python code run within sublime text 3 (with Build) inconsistent with same code run in the Python shell?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-re

**Python code:**

```
import re
foo = "abcdefghiv fsd ,,,,df134223"
pattern = re.compile('fsd')
matches = pattern.finditer(foo)
for match in matches:
     print(match)
```

**Sublime output after ctrl B**

```
sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f1968a33dc0 
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

**Python shell code:**

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)  [GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more
information.
import re
foo = "abcdefghiv fsd ,,,,df134223"
pattern = re.compile('fsd')
matches = pattern.finditer(foo)
for match in matches:   
    print(match)
```

**Python shell output:**

```
sre.SRE_Match object; span=(11, 14), match='fsd'>
```

Why is it printing 'sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f1968a33dc0' in one case
and 'sre.SRE_Match object; span=(11, 14), match='fsd'>' in the other?

Comment: Probably different versions of Python.

Comment: I think that may be it! When I check the version with print(sys.version) in sublime it's 2.7.17 on the Pythin shell I see it's 3.6.9

Comment: The `Python.sublime-build` that ships with Sublime just executes `python`; it's up to you to make sure that's the version you want or make your own build file that executes the version you want.